# Ошибка при отправке сообщений между Client(С#) и Server(Java)

Tags: java, android, c#, windows, сокет

Необходимо сделать обмен сообщениями между устройствами на ОС Windows и Android. Сервер запущен на Android и отправляет сообщение на ПК Windows. Трудность состоит в том, что для получение сообщений (C# Windows)работает, а на Android (java) отправка не работает, выдаётся ошибка.

Код (получения c# клиент, рабочий)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That program can transfer small file. I've test up to 850kb file");
            IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 1818);
            Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);

             byte[] clientData = new byte[10];
             //string receivedPath = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/";

             int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

             string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData);

             Console.WriteLine("Messenge    :" +  fileName + "-файл число");
             clientSock.Close();
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Sending fail." + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Код отправки Java (не рабочий, с ошибкой)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileLocation;
    int portNo;

    Main.send(1818);//(ошибка)
}
public static  void send(int portNo) throws IOException
{

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream dOut = null;
    String mes = "messenge"; // сообщение
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
        System.out.println("Waiting for receiver...");
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);

            byte [] filenm =  mes.getBytes();//строку в массив байтов
            // отправка на удалённый сервер 
            outputStream.write(filenm); (ошибка в этой строке)
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("Отправлено сообщение" + mes);

        }
        finally {
            if (bufferedInputStream != null) bufferedInputStream.close();
            if (outputStream != null) bufferedInputStream.close();
            if (socket!=null) socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.Main.send(Main.java:35)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной, которая иницилизированна `null` и справедливо получаете `java.lang.NullPointerException` (объекта нет, обращаться не к чему). Сперва вам необходимо создать экземпляр `OutputStream` и только после этого обращаться к его членам.

Comment: null инициализировать по-другому невозможно. Создал экземпляр OutputStream, но это не помогло проблеме. Ошибка остаётся, результата - нет

Comment: `Null` это нулевая ссылка, т.е. ссылка, которая не указывает ни на один объект в куче. В вашем примере вы инициализируете переменную типа `OutputStream` нулом: `OutputStream outputStream = null` теперь, в стеке есть переменная `outputStream` типа `OutputStream` которая не указывает ни на один объект. Для того, что бы обратиться к членам `OutputStream`, переменная `outputStream` должна быть инициализирована экземпляром `OutputStream`, в противном случае вы получите тот самый `NullPointerException`. Конкретно для вашего примера, что-то вроде: `outputStream = serverSocket.getOutputStream()`

Comment: исправил, всё работает, благодарю за помощь